# How to store data as array in native storage?

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to store some details in native storage as `array` when clicking in `button`. How to store data in native storage as `array` and how to get it?

Comment: At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Answer (score 0):

For ionic v2 we can use native storage

Add plugins using cmd

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-nativestorage
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/native-storage
```

In appmodule.ts

```
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    // pages to be added         
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        NgCalendarModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
       //pages to be added

    ],
    providers: [
        SplashScreen,
        NativeStorage,
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

To set and get values
    import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';

```
var array=[];
this.nativeStorage.setItem("setting value", array);
this.nativeStorage.getItem("setting value"),then(
 data => {
    console.log("stored value", data)
})
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` :

```
let myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

// Save to storage :
this.storage.set('data_key', JSON.stringify(myArray));

// Get from storage :
this.storage.get('data_key').then( (data) => {
  this.result = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Comment: what if I want to add 'd' after inserting all the fields. Like in a separate command?